# How can I display the data returned from the solidity function?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Here is a js file that will try to get the list of departments entered into the system. I wanted to display all the department's name in a html page. But nothing is displaying.
Below code is the js file

```
App = {
    web3Provider: null,
    contracts: {},

  init:async function() {
  return  App.initWeb3();
  },
    initWeb3: async function() {
     // Modern dapp browsers...
  if (window.ethereum) {
    App.web3Provider = window.ethereum;
    try {
      // Request account access
      await window.ethereum.enable();
    } catch (error) {
      // User denied account access...
      console.error("User denied account access")
    }
  }
  // Legacy dapp browsers...
  else if (window.web3) {
    App.web3Provider = window.web3.currentProvider;
  }
  // If no injected web3 instance is detected, fall back to Ganache
  else {
    App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
  }
  web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
      return App.initContract();
    },

    initContract: function() {
      $.getJSON('department.json', function(data) {
        // Get the necessary contract artifact file and instantiate it with truffle-contract
        var AdoptionArtifact = data;
        App.contracts.department = TruffleContract(AdoptionArtifact);

        // Set the provider for our contract
        App.contracts.department.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

        // Use our contract to retrieve and mark the adopted pets
      });

      return App.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
       return App.submit;
    },



    submit: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();


      var adoptionInstance;

  web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    var account = accounts[0];

    App.contracts.department.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      adoptionInstance = instance;

      // Execute adopt as a transaction by sending account
      return adoptionInstance.getid();
    }).then(function(result) {
      alert("hi");
        var numdept = result.length

        //const FIELD_ADDR  = 0;
        //const FIELD_FUNDS = 1;

        var peopleStructs = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <=numdept; i++) {
          var x=Promise.resolve(adoptionInstance.getname(i));
          x.then(function(value) {

            document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML=value;
            const person = {
                name:value,
            };
            peopleStructs.push(person);
            // expected output: 123
          });

        }
        alert(peopleStructs);
      //window.location.href="login.html"

    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
  });
    }

  };

  $(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
      App.init();
    });
  });
```

Here I am attaching the department.sol

```
 pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Department
{

    struct Departmentinfo 
    {
        string Dep_name;
        string email;
        string location;
        uint256 contact_no;

    }


    uint256 id=0;
    mapping(uint256 => Departmentinfo) Departments;
    uint256[] public DepartmentIds;


    function registerDepartment(string memory name, string memory location,string memory email, uint256 contact_no) public returns(uint256)    
         {
                id=id+1;
                Departmentinfo storage newDept = Departments[id];
                newDept.Dep_name = name;
                newDept.location=location;
                newDept.email = email;
                newDept.contact_no = contact_no;
                DepartmentIds.push(id);
         }

    function getDepartmentDetails(uint256 deptid) public view returns (string memory, string memory,string memory, uint256)
         {
               Departmentinfo storage d = Departments[deptid];
               return(d.Dep_name,d.location,d.email,d.contact_no);
         }

    function getdept(uint256 deptid) public view returns (string memory)
         {
                Departmentinfo storage d = Departments[deptid];
                return(d.Dep_name);
         }

    function comparestring(string memory a , string memory b) public view returns(bool)
        {
           return (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a))==keccak256(abi.encodePacked(b)));

        }
        function getid() public view returns(uint256)
        {
            return id;
        }
        function getname(uint256 mid) public view returns(string memory)
        {
            Departmentinfo storage d=Departments[mid];
            return(d.Dep_name);
        }

    function validatedept(string memory email,uint256 contact_no) public view returns (uint256 )
        {
            uint256 deptid=0;
            uint256 n=id;
            for(uint256 i=1;i<=n;i++)
             {
                Departmentinfo storage d=Departments[i];
                string memory chck_email=d.email;
                uint256 chck_contact_no=d.contact_no;
                if((comparestring(chck_email,email)) && (chck_contact_no==contact_no))
                     {
                        deptid=id;
                         break;
                     }
             }

             return deptid;
        }
```

So I am seeking help from anyone in the community to guide me. Thanks in advance.

```
}
```

Comment: Too much information. Please post only the code which is relevant to the question.

Comment: For the department.sol getDepartmentDetails() is the function that is returning the value

Comment: I actually agree with @goodvibration. Where in the js are you even calling getDepartmentDetails()?

Comment: I am sorry... I am calling getname() function

Comment: I'll rephrase myself. Please rewrite your entire question (**the question, not the comments**). Please make sure to add **all** the necessary details and **only** the necessary details. This should include both your Solidity code and your Javascript code. Again - everything necessary to answer the question, and only what's necessary to answer the question.

Comment: @ParthaPratimSarkarChoito From your code its look like you are using web3 v0.20 with MetaMask, AFAIK that combination doesn't support synchronous calls so `Promise.resolve(adoptionInstance.getname(i))` will fail. Also it seems your function `submit` is not being called, in `bindEvents` it is missing the parenthesis `return App.submit;`